# Unable to fetch values of range of cells in custom function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was working on a problem which requires input an array and output is also an array. I wrote the VBA code (after I had done workings of logic on notebook) but I don't know why this code is unable to fetch values of input.

I have already written the code. Just help me with the syntax!
As I am not a professional coder, please ignore the naming of variables. Also, I am new to this platform, so I am not aware of many rules. Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks!

Test cases and error:

[image]

```
Public Function Get1_GEM(vector As Range)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, i1 As Long, j1 As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
Dim GEM() As Double
ReDim GEM(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Double
Dim res() As Double
ReDim res(1 To 3) As Double
Dim row() As Double
ReDim row(1 To 3) As Double
For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
    For j = 1 To 2 Step 1
        GEM(i, j) = 2 * i + j - 2
        row(i) = 0
    Next j
Next i
Dim inp() As Double
ReDim inp(1 To 3) As Double
i = 0
j = 0
Dim x() As Double
ReDim x(1 To 3) As Double
Dim y() As Double
ReDim y(1 To 3) As Double
i = 0
For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
    inp(i) = vector.Cells(i, 1)
Next i

For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
    For j = 1 To 2 Step 1
        If GEM(i, j) = inp(1) Then
            x(1) = i
            y(1) = j
            row(i) = row(i) + 1
        ElseIf GEM(i, j) = inp(2) Then
            x(2) = i
            y(2) = j
            row(i) = row(i) + 1
        ElseIf GEM(i, j) = inp(3) Then
            x(3) = i
            y(3) = j
            row(i) = row(i) + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
i = 0
j = 0
If row(1) > 0 And row(2) > 0 And row(3) > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
        res(i) = GEM(x(i), 2 - y(i))
    Next i
Else

    If row(1) = 0 Then
        a = 0
    ElseIf row(2) = 0 Then
        a = 1
    ElseIf row(3) = 0 Then
        a = 2
    End If

    If row(1) = 1 Then
        b = 0
    ElseIf row(2) = 1 Then
        b = 1
    ElseIf row(3) = 1 Then
        b = 2
    End If
    c = 3 - a - b
    Dim d As Double
        If x(1) = b Then
            d = 0
        ElseIf x(2) = b Then
            d = 1
        ElseIf x(3) = b Then
            d = 2
        End If
i = 0
For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
    If i = d Then
        res(i) = GEM(x(i), 2 - y(i))
    Else
        res(i) = GEM(a, y(i))
    End If
Next i
End If
Get1_GEM = res
End Function
```

Comment: please show some test data input and what is expected as output.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ya sure. Let me send you the link to screenshot!

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: you are saying you want a range as an output with the `As Range` on the Function line, but your output is not a range but numbers.  Remove that part from the end function line.

Comment: No, output is also a range. Please refer the screenshot attached! Or maybe, I am confusing with the term "range". If output is coming in more than 1 cell, then it is range - at least that is what I am considering the range.!

Comment: No the output is an array of numbers not a range.  You are putting the array of numbers in a range.  there is a difference.

Comment: @ScottCraner Then, what should I do? Can you please tell me what syntax I should use to get correct results?

Comment: "Output is coming in more than one cell". This is your confusion. A `range` is a `cell` or `cells`. A `cell` is an actual cell on the spreadsheet. Your `res` has no cells in it, just doubles/numbers. `res` is just an array of double. As it is not a cell or a group of cells it is not a `range`. Your function definition should then be something like `Public Function Get1_GEM(vector As Range) As Variant` so that whoever calls this can expect a generic response which that caller will then need to know is going to be an array of doubles.

Comment: `Public Function Get1_GEM(vector As Range)`

Comment: @JNevill the `()` after vector needs to be removed also.

Comment: @ScottCraner Woah boy. Missed that. Thanks.

Comment: also change the last line to `Get1_GEM = Application.Transpose(res)`.  Then when you enter the formula, highlight all three cells. Put the formula in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter the formula across all three cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner and JNevill Still, No progress. I have edited the code whatever edit you suggested. Please take a look!

Comment: now that you changed the code in the question, which is frowned upon, you should no get an error.  At least I do not get an error, with only changing that.

Comment: You also want `res(i) = GEM(x(i), 3 - y(i))` not `res(i) = GEM(x(i), 2 - y(i))`

Comment: @ScottCraner -  Thanks Sir. Just corrected the code. Worked like a charm. Thanks!